# Importing CSV file to mySQL with response Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '27-JUL-2019' for column 'Transaction Date'

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file to mySQL. Below is the statement that I used:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/XXX.csv'
INTO TABLE tdf_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But i am getting this response:

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '27-JUL-2019' for column
>   'Transaction Date' at row 1

Please note that the CSV file has a column which is in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format.

Comment: Does the file contain `27-JUL-2019` or `27/07/2019`?

Comment: probably the format, check your database, to see which one is the accepted one. If it is not, check if there is some restriction in the database for this field (e.g. this has to be unique)